# The gravitational hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, schroedinger-equation

Suppose we take the quantum mechanical hydrogen atom and replace the proton with a black hole. Consider the black hole to be the same mass as the proton, to be uncharged and to provide a similar gravitational attraction as the Coulomb attraction would apply in the standard scenario. How would the energy levels of the the electron be effected (let us assume that we can ignore complications coming from QFT, such as Hawking radiation)?

I do not believe we should expect the angular equations to be changed, but i believe the radial equation should be altered due to what now will be the Schwarzschild geometry. It is not clear to me how this would be done. Furthermore, the standard coulomb potential would need to be replaced by the gravitational potential, but since this is of the same form i cannot see it having too much of an impact on the energy levels.

Would they infact not change (at least in any dramatic sense, only be rescalled)? Or would the impact of the geometry have some considerable effect?

Ofcourse this is perhaps a question that can only really be answered by a quantum theory of gravity, but what could we infer from the considerations above, and can anyone suggest how to incorporate the geometry into the radial equation?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. In particular: is the black hole supposed to be the same mass as the proton? Is it supposed to possess electric charge (equal to the proton?)? If not charged, is it supposed to be massive enough to provide similar gravitational attraction of the electron as the proton would by electric force? The answers to the questions you ask will all depend on the answers to these questions about the scenario.

Comment: If the black hole has an event horizon I guess it will lurk in the dark until it can feast on the poor electron!

Comment: @The_Sympathizer these are good points, apologizes for the lack of clarity. Let us suppose that the black hole is the mass of the proton, is uncharged, and that the gravitational attraction will provide a similar one to that of the coulomb.

Comment: @Jack Hughes : Thanks. Might be good to put that in the question tagline; this qn has accrued 1 close vote already.

Comment: I don't think the system could be modeled by a Coloumn interaction. Quantum gravity would be important.

Comment: Two issues, first, the black hole is too small, it will quickly evaporate, second the electron should be very close, i.e. inside the event horizon

Comment: Is the question what the energy levels of the electron are in an effective Schwarzchild potential $$V(r) = -\frac{GMm}{r} + \frac{L^2}{2\mu r} + \frac{G(M+m) L^2}{ r^{3}}$$
when the first term is comparable in strength to the usual Coulomb interaction?

This is a solvable math problem (I think), even if it's not sensible physically

Comment: @user1504 I think this is most in line with the reasoning I had and the question I was attempting to ask. Any links for this effective potential? I have not come across it before and assumed that it behaved only as the Newtonian potential, not with these additional terms.

Comment: It's the equation for the proper time radial motion of a test particle orbiting a Schwarzchild black hole.  You have to ignore the effect of the test particle on the hole to trust this.  The wikipedia article has a decent derivation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics